# Show that there exists $C,\epsilon>0$ such that $|e^{-\pi z^2x}|\leq C(|z|+1)^{-1-\epsilon}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $U=\{z\in \mathbb C| |Im( z)|<\delta\}$. Note: we can choose delta to be small enough such that the statement holds.

Show that there exists $C,\epsilon>0$ such that $|e^{-\pi z^2x}|\leq C(|z|+1)^{-1-\epsilon}$ for all $z\in U$. Note: ($x\in \mathbb R_{>0}$ and $x$ is fixed).

Does anyone even know where to begin. All I have is that $|e^{-\pi z^2x}|=e^{-\pi Re(z^2)x}=e^{-\pi |z|^2cos(2\theta)x}$. Can we use that fact that $e^{x}\geq  x+1$?

Hints or solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: $\Re((a+ib)^2 x) = x a^2+O(1)$, $|e^{-\pi z^2 x}| \le e^{-\pi x(|z|^2-\delta^2)}$

Comment: Thanks, but could you elaborate your comment. I still cant see how we can get  a C or $\epsilon$

Comment: Who decays faster, $e^{-t^2}$ or $1/t^2$ ?

Comment: Im sorry could you explain how you got $|e^{-\pi z^2 x}|\leq |e^{-\pi x(|z|^2-\delta^2)}|$